# When and Why does ScalarDB throw UnknownTransactionStatusException

Tags: scalardb

From the example https://github.com/indetail-blockchain/getting-started-with-scalardb, transaction.commit can throw two exceptions

•   CommitException which indicates a commit has failed. In that case, it is recommended to roll back the transaction using transaction.abort()
•   UnknownTransactionStatusException indicates the transaction commit is in an unknown status. It may or not have been committed.

1. Does abort guarantee rollback?
2. In what cases is UnknownTransactionStatusException thrown?
3. What is the remedy if UnknownTransactionStatusException is thrown? Shall I call abort? Would that guarantee rollback to previous consistent state?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Does abort guarantee rollback?

Actually in the current implementation based on Snapshot Isolation,
`abort()` is not really needed, so as you can see the code, `abort()` is doing nothing.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/scalar/db/transaction/consensuscommit/ConsensusCommit.java#L126

To abort, only thing you need to do is throwing away a transaction object before calling `commit()`.
In that case, nothing happens in the storage, so it looks like it is properly rollbacked.

If you have already called `commit()`, whether or not it will really commit or abort depends on the transaction's mutations and storage availability.
If everything goes well, it will be committed. If it faces some conflicts or failure, it will be aborted.
In any cases, it will be committed (roll-forwarded) or aborted (roll-backed) eventually.

> 2. In what cases is UnknownTransactionStatusException thrown?

There is a case where it can not identify if a transaction is committed or aborted  , for example, due to some catastrophic failure in a system, and `UnknownTransactionStatusException` is thrown in such case.

> 3. What is the remedy if UnknownTransactionStatusException is thrown? Shall I call abort? Would that guarantee rollback to previous consistent state?

When `UnknownTransactionStatusException` is thrown, there is nothing you can do except for waiting until the status is settled.
You can call `TransactionService.getState()` to check if the transaction is committed or aborted eventually.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/scalar/db/service/TransactionService.java#L70